# How to change URL `OpenWith` in Edge browser

Tags: tfs, microsoft-edge, tfs-2015

When use Edge open the Build's Url in TFS,the edge browser popup the `Open with` dialog .my fault choose chrome,Now I must right click open the url.

How can I change the `OpenWith`?

[image]

> **[Update:]**After I Reset the default app in setting panel. I reopen(single click) the URL will Show the dialog.
>   [image]

Comment: Could you provide  a  screenshot   to show how to open with the build url?Did you open it in chrome by default now?

Comment: @Patrick open the url `2015.0.293.3` will open chrome,and it's just a blank tab.no content.

Comment: Is Chrome the default browser? How about you set the Edge to be the default browser?

Comment: @Vicky-MSFT After I reset the default browser(BTW. edge is always default browser). show the dialog to choose `open with `? I have updated the question.Please!

Comment: @huoxudong125, after you set Edge to the default browser, please close Edge instances, clear cache and try again.